# CAB file for X86 and X64

Tags: activex, com-interop, setup-project

HI

I have created a CAB file for an ActiveX component which is wrapper around a .Net Libray.

Here the .Net Library is refering some third party components which are actually build in (X86 or X64) No Any CPU.

So My Cab file should be intelligent enogh to install eigther X86 or X64 depending on the client ( Browser)

I Know the change should be in the INF file.

As i am new to thsi Interoperabilit technology.

Please guide me in solving this problem.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/32ec4e8f-cded-4f39-b57b-bea2222fdb92